# Why is the norm of a linear function $\| w \|^2$ and not $\langle c, X X^T c \rangle $?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, mathematical-statistics

I asked [Why is the regularization penality equal to $\langle c , Kc \rangle_{R^n}$ when using the kernel trick in Tikhonov regularization?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242819/why-is-the-regularization-penality-equal-to-langle-c-kc-rangle-rn-when) and got good answers, however, there is still one detail that does not quite make sense to me. Why is the norm when using Tikhonov regularization equal to:

$$ \| w \|^2_{\mathbb R^d} = x^T x$$

and not equal to:

$$ \langle c, X X^T c \rangle_{\mathbb R^d} = c X X^T c?$$

My intuition tells me that this should be a trivial question, embarrassingly I am unable to resolve it.

Usually in Tikhonov regularization we have the norm of a funciton be $\| f \|^2_{\mathcal H} = \langle f, f \rangle_{\mathcal H}$. Using the feature map $\Phi$ and the kernel trick $w = \Phi^T c$ one can show:

$$ \| f \|^2_{\mathcal H} = \langle f,f \rangle_{\mathcal H} = \langle w,w \rangle = \langle \phi^Tc,\Phi^Tc \rangle = \langle c,\Phi \Phi^Tc \rangle = \langle c,Kc \rangle .$$

In the case of linear functions we have:

$$ f(x) = \langle w, x \rangle = \sum^D_{d=1} w_i x_i .$$

If that is the case, then why don't we have as the norm in standard Tikhhonov regularization:

$$ \| f \|^2_{\mathcal H} = \langle f,f \rangle_{\mathcal H} = \langle w,w \rangle = \langle X^Tc,X^Tc \rangle = \langle c,X X^Tc \rangle? $$

Wouldn't that be a more consistent view of Tikhonov regularization?

Comment: How is that $\mathscr w = X^{T}c$ ? What is the intuition?